# ActiveMQ heap increases even using persitent storage

Tags: activemq-classic

In my project we are using activemq queue with Kahadb as persistance mechanism. Though we have enought disk space, we see that 6GB of RAM is also increasing. Any idea why heap should increase when the persistance is in kahadb. IS there anyway to completely offload heap to persistance storge?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot and most likely would not be happy with performance if it offloaded everything in the heap to disk. Its most likely caching messages, which is a major performance boost.
2. Connect to the broker using jconsole.. invoke a garbage collection at the java level and the "GC" operation on the broker object. It should go down.

Note: The "shark tooth" heap graph isn't always readily visible with a busy message broker, since it favors caching messages for performance.